# Search through set of files designated by multiple globs with Vimgrep

Tags: search, vim, vimgrep

Does anyone know syntax of Vimgrep to search with multiple file globs? I am trying to use this command to search in the current directory.

```
map <F3> :execute "vimgrep /" . expand("<cword>") . "/j **/*.c* *.txt" <Bar> cw<CR>
```

With using this command, Vim searches only for `*.c*`. Any idea about how to search for multiple filetypes?

Answer (score 25):

To search for "text" in all *.txt & *.php files recursively from current directory.

```
:vimgrep "text" **/*.txt **/*.php
```

Comment: I would also add, that typing `:cn` and `:cp` to go to the _next_ and _previous_ matches respectively.

Comment: This will get annoying confirming infos when one of the given types doesn't exit.

Comment: `"**/*.php" [new directory]·\n"[Quickfix list]...\n Press Enter to continue" `

Answer (score 4):

in this directory

```
:vimgrep "search subject" *.c
:vimgrep blah *.[ch]
:vimgrep blah *.c* *.h
```

in this or any descendant directory

```
:vimgrep "search subject" ./**/*.c
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't need the ./ for it to work recursively in the current dir.

Answer (score 0):

I am just getting into Vim and this question taught me about the existence of vimgrep. Is there a way to loop through the results? So say I wanted to find all of the instances of "user", and I use

```
:vimgrep /user/g **/*.rb
```

How could I loops through the instances of that text?

Comment: These results get added to the quicklist window. You can open the quicklist window with ":copen" and can loop through the results

Comment: Umm, khebbie, this was over a year ago? Thanks for the feedback.